# Save the output of Azure Machine Learning jobs to a specific location using the azure ML UI interface

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines

I'm new to Azure and Azure ML studio.
I'm currently trying to bring a data processing pipeline I have built in local to cloud for a project I've been working on. I'd like to know if the "flow" I'm following is the right approach, and in case, a solution to the problem I'll explain below.

I have reached my current state of the work through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/?view=azureml-api-2), and through some good old "try-and-error" approach.
My main problem is that I  have create a job with a custom pipeline from a python script through the azure ML UI, but I don't know how to save the output file of this pipeline in a specific location, instead of the one provided by the system.

Down here the steps I've followed:

1. I'm setting up a job in azure ML, creating a job clicking on "create job(preview)"
   [image]
2. Here I proceed selecting a compute instance and a custom environment I built from my local experiment.
   Then, as shown in the picture below, I upload from a local folder the files that represent my pipeline process:
   [image]
3. Then I create the file in input to my file "main.py" using the "create input" field as follow:
   [image]
4. ...and I do the same thing with the output section, creating the "path" to the output file:
   [image]
5. therefore, the command shell script I execute will be:
   [image]

everything works here, which means that I can read the file in input, and I can save the file in output.
The main problem is that the output path is pointing into a blob storage which is not the one I'd like to use it.
I'd like to save the file into the same blob storage and container where I am reading the file, but when I create the output in the step 4, I cannot specify the location, is built automatically by Azure ML.

Can someone tell me how to handle this output issue in order to save where I want a file? Is it possible to do it through the Azure ML UI, or do I have to resort to some code inserted inside my python script? If this is the case, can you provide such code?

Thank you so much for your time, I tried to be as complete as possible in the explaination.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I think you can upload your output to your blob storage in your python script itself.
Add below code in your script.

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("your connection string of storage account")
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="your container name", blob="blob name)

with  open(file='filepath to upload'), mode="rb") as  cnt:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data=cnt, blob_type="BlockBlob",overwrite=True)
```

This above code will add your output file to blob storage.
Below is the result to my script.

[image]

For more information about uploading to blob storage [refer this documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python#upload-data-to-a-block-blob)